# Is it possible to write a codegenerator like the GUI Builder style for Codename one?

Tags: code-generation, codenameone

I am writing an app for industrial environment.

There are different roles and different views onto the same data within a single app.

Looking forward to **customization for special needs** of different customers, I want to be able to give each worker/viewer the opportunity to create their own layout.

I give you this example:

- First you have a blank 'form' where you can add a simple Layout (contained in cn1. Maybe BorderLayout, BoxLayout and GridLayout. **Not more**)
- Next you can add **predefined** components to these layouts, that are hardwired to the objects attributes (drag and drop)
- Once the user clicks 'save', the app that he is logged in with, updates the 'MainForm', where the data of the object is shown according to the self-build layout he just made.

---

**Going into the use case:**

There are 3 Tasks to be overviewed.

The managers view (he just wants to see the name and the status) may be something like this:

```
|    Tasks     |
----------------
| status name1 |
| status name2 |
| status name3 |
```

While the worker, who is actually doing the work, wants a more detailed view of it:

```
|    Tasks     |
----------------
| status name1 |
   - step 1 
   - step 2
 startd - endd 
| status name2 |
  ......
```

(startd = startDate, endd = endDate)

Another, second worker may not want to see every single step of execution, as he is doing the work since 1960 and knows what to do.

In this case, there would be the components `status`, `name`, `steps`,`startd`,`endd` etc. and the user could drag and drop them to create the view they want. the result is a container. Each object, that is represented will be added to an infinite scroll container.

---

**Now my question:**

1) Is it possible to give each user of an app the opportunity to give
   the data it holds a custom view of it? 
  2) If yes, what would be the best way to generate the code needed? (In a web-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The [new Codename One GUI builder](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-gui-builder.html) is a Codename One app, it can actually run on devices although at the moment this isn't our main target.

There are quite a few Codename One developers who use XML to determine the layouts of specific screens in runtime probably trying to replicate your use case.

Comment: Wow, this new GUI Builder looks awesome!

Comment: But please tell me, is this xml-layout thing android-specific? If not, can you provide an example how to use?

Comment: There is the XML that is a part of our GUI builder which is done during build time for all OS's. You can write your own XML parsing logic and layout the components in any way you want which will also work for all OS's.